# Codemagic - "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to set up codemagic ios flow. I want to build ipa and push it to TestFlight. I've created codemagic api key in AppStoreConnect, and created Developer & Distribution Certificates via Codemagic interface by Generating a new code signing certificate option. I also created a Provisioning profile for my app and it says that Push Notification Capability is enabled.

But when I start the process I have an error:

```
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.
```

I'm new to codemagic and tried to do all steps by docs, but I can't understand this problem :( Maybe someone can help to fix the problem?

This is my flow:

```
ios-workflow-id:
    name: iOS Sample Workflow
    integrations:
      app_store_connect: CodeMagic
    environment:
      vars:
        APP_ID: #########
      ios_signing:
        provisioning_profiles:
          - Codemagic
        certificates:
          - Development_Certificate
          - Distribution_Certificate
    scripts:
      - name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
        script: |
          xcode-project use-profiles
      - name: Get Flutter packages
        script: |
          flutter packages pub get
      - name: Install pods
        script: |
          find . -name "Podfile" -execdir pod install \;
      - name: Flutter build ipa
        script: |
          BUILD_NUMBER=$(($(app-store-connect get-latest-app-store-build-number "$APP_ID") + 1))
          flutter build ipa --release \
            --build-name=1.0.0 \
            --build-number=$BUILD_NUMBER
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
    publishing:
      app_store_connect:
        auth: integration
        submit_to_testflight: true
```

Code signing logs:

```
Configure code signing settings
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.mobileprovision
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.provisionprofile
List available code signing certificates in keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/03-02-23_smdje8o8.keychain-db
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/clone/**/*.xcodeproj
Completed configuring code signing settings
 - Using profile "Codemagic" [717112ed-c3ca-45b5-946a-efe6d07dffcc] for target "Runner" [Debug] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "Codemagic" [717112ed-c3ca-45b5-946a-efe6d07dffcc] for target "Runner" [Profile] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "Codemagic" [717112ed-c3ca-45b5-946a-efe6d07dffcc] for target "Runner" [Release] from project "Runner"
Generated options for exporting the project
 - Method: app-store
 - Provisioning Profiles:
     - com.fdforge.dev: Codemagic
 - Signing Certificate: Apple Distribution
 - Signing Style: manual
 - Team Id: #####
Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist
```

Comment: can you update your question to include log output from `xcode-project use-profiles` command to ensure it uses correct provisioning profile?

Comment: also do I have to use profile with Developer mode or App-Store? If I want to send build to the TestFlight.
I tried both, the result is the same, but am I right that I use app store mode for this?

Comment: @MikhailTokarev I've updated my question with logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!
I had to create export.plist file:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd”>
<plist version=“1.0”>
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.example.appName</key>
        <string>Provisioning profile name</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iOS Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>your team id</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And changed the command for building IPA:

```
- name: Flutter build ipa
        script: |
          flutter build ipa --export-options-plist ios/export.plist --build-number=5 --build-name=1.0.0 --release
```

And it works!)

Comment: Can this be placed in the same folder with info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

This question and **@Veronika's** answer helped me fix the same issue.  I later found documentation directly from Apple that provides more detail on what is needed:  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev86f8cf93d

The article is titled: **"Configure a bot to create distribution-signed iOS App (IPA) files"**.

In the end, for my specific needs I created a `buildInfo.plist` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
      <key>com.company.app</key>
      <string>Provisioning Profile Name</string>
    </dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>YOUR_TEAM_ID</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```